# How to add a line space under and image which uses a clear:both

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with line spacing after an image. Basically if you look at the screenshot below, you can see that `5. Work Hard, Play Hard` and `6. Motivation` is right under the picture.

I want to create a line space underneath but it's weird because I have to do `<br/><br/>` under `5. Work Hard, Play Hard` and `<br/><br/><br/>` under `6. Motivation`.

I don't like doing this so want to understand best way of adding that break?

[image]

code:

```
<img src="img/friendships.png" height="200" width="250" alt="Metis Skills and Careers Build Friendships" style="float: left; margin: 3px 12px 3px 0px; border: 1px solid #000000;">
            
            <p>Building relationships, as with any industry, is a great part of the charm and IT is no exception. Like-minded people with similar zest for knowledge makes it even more exciting to perform well at your job. </p>
            
            <p>Mayur, being in the IT sector for 10+ years, says -</p>
            
            <p><i>“This is one of my favourite ones. I have built friendships with colleagues I have worked with over the years and I know you will too. You will have plenty of opportunities.”</i></p>
            
            <p style="clear: both;"><b>5. Work Hard, Play Hard</b></p>
            
            <img src="img/play-hard.png" height="200" width="250" alt="Metis Skills and Careers Build Friendships" style="float: left; margin: 3px 12px 3px 0px; border: 1px solid #000000;">
            
            <p>IT provides a lot of social activities during and after work including board games, video games, after work drinks, hackathons, meals, attending tech events and other things they can think of. 
            It’s your choice how much you want to socialise or not, but it’s great to have that option.</p>
            
            <p style="clear: both;"><b>6. Motivation</b></p>
            
            <p>Creating new tech, working on cool features, learning new skills, socialising with friends, all of these provide you motivation. 
            It’s a creative sector with plenty of opportunities to learn and continue to push yourself because there’s so much interest and a vast amount of knowledge to explore. 
            Working in IT is a natural motivator.</p>
```

Comment: use margin? ...

Comment: give more code + css. please

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov the relevant code is already in the question

Comment: @Temani Afif, ok, sorry. did not notice with sleepy eyes :)

Comment: Sorted, will post my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put a 
 within the paragraph you're performing the `clear:both`

```
<p style="clear: both;"><br/><b>5. Work Hard, Play Hard</b></p>

...

<p style="clear: both;"><br/><b>6. Motivation</b></p>
```